# Ошибка при установке Debian

Tags: linux, debian

При установке возникает ошибка. Помогите разобраться и установить или скачать микропрограмму.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что мешает скачать эти файлы, записать на USB Flash drive и дать установщику установить?

Comment: Я понятия не имею где их скачать. Если поможете буду весьма благодарен.

Comment: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-atheros_20210818-1_all.deb

Comment: Можете скачать образ Debian с предустановленными драйверами https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/

Comment: Драйвера нужно распаковать?

Comment: Да, deb-файл целиком распаковать как есть

Comment: И последний вопрос. Их нужно скопировать на отдельную флешку или на ту же где и установочный образ?

Comment: На отдельную желательно, хотя можно и на установочную

Comment: К сожалению ничего не получается. Он не подтягивает Файлы с флешки

Comment: Попробуйте поновее http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-atheros_20210315-3_all.deb. Попробуйте распаковать только ath10k из data.tar.xz/lib/firmware/

Answer (score 2):

Пропусти этот шаг. После установки скачай https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/all/firmware-atheros/download и установи `sudo dpkg -i firmware-atheros_20210315-3_all.deb`